# Android Studio: Multiple APKs for Multiple Modules

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android is there a way to generate signed APKs for all modules in a project.
E.g. I have following project

```
Project
  -- Library Module
  -- Module 1
  -- Module 2
  -- Module 3
```

I want to generate APKs for all 3 modules in one command. Currently I have to separately use Generate Dialog for all 3 which takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can generate multiple apk files with gradlew.

Open Terminal Window in Android Studio and run following commands:

1- Navigate to root folder of the project, where gradlew file is located

```
cd ..
```

2- Give executable permissions to gradlew (this needs to be done only once, no need to repeat again)

```
chmod a+x gradlew
```

3- Generate debuggable apks of all underlying modules.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

You can also generate release apk files for all modules, by using this command instead

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

for more details, run the following command to see list of all tasks that can be run on gradlew

```
./gradlew tasks
```

Note: Running ./gradlew first time might result in terminal downloading the gradle files from server, wait for the downloading to complete before moving forward!

Hope that helps!

**Update:**
For providing signing information in grade file, Open your module specific build.grade file and update it to contain this code:

```
signingConfigs {
    playstore {
        keyAlias 'KEY_ALIS_NAME_HERE'
        storeFile file('/PATH_TO_KEYSTORE_FILE_HERE/app.keystore')
        keyPassword 'KEY_PASSWORD_HERE'
        storePassword 'STORE_PASSWORD_HERE'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-file.txt'
        proguardFile 'proguard-file.txt'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.playstore
    }
}
```

After that you can simply run `./gradlew assembleRelease` to do the work :)

Comment: Thanks this works. But it is generating unsigned APKs. Is there a way to generate signed APKs?

Comment: Modify your module specific build.gradle and specify signing configuration there for release.. and assembleRelease would automatically execute it!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Asif Mujteba. This is going to help me a lot.

Comment: @Asif Mujteba i am on windows and console gives me '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command", can you help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672417/how-to-generate-signed-apks-for-separate-modules-in-android-studio