# How to generate signed APKs for separate modules in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play

My project having 3 modules

```
include ':app'
include ':videograbber'
include ':audiograbber'
```

Now I want to generate Signed APK for module Videograbber

When I used Generate Signed APK (app bundle) in Android Studio , It directly generating for 'app' without asking any selection screens

I don't know how to generate for other modules

I read this question : [Android Studio: Multiple APKs for Multiple Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255618/android-studio-multiple-apks-for-multiple-modules)

But it only have CLI based solution . I need to do it via studio

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, remember that you have to apply the plugin `com.android.application` in the modules in which you want to generate an APK.

Second of all, my solution works on Android Studio **3.6.1**.

You can go on `Build` -> `Generate Signed Bundle / APK...` and this window will be opened:

[image: Generate Bundle / APK window]

You have to select `APK` and press `Next`.
After doing that, this other window will be opened:

[image: Select module window]

In the `Module` picker of this window, you can choose the module you prefer (e.g. `:videograbber`) and generate the APK for the selected module.

Comment: You cannot click next without specifying a keystore location, though

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a task in Gradle combining all the assembles, then you can use AndroidStudio to run the task.